# Apache reverse proxy match requests

Tags: apache, redirect

My server hosts two web services： WordPress(on Port 8080) and Flask(on Port 8081). I am setting up a reverse proxy as I want any requests start with /admin goes to Flask and all others go to Wordpress.

For example:

```
http://aa.mcmaster.ca/admin/aa    Goes to Port 8080
http://aa.mcmaster.ca/page1       Goes to Port 8081
http://aa.mcmaster.ca/page1       Goes to Port 8081
```

My setting is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /wordpress/wp-content
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName aa.mcmaster.ca
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /admin http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /admin  http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /wordpress/wp-content
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName aa.mcmaster.ca
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

It doesn't work. I am stuck on how to set up to matchs requests other than `/admin`. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below ProxyPass in a single VirtualHost and test.

```
ProxyPass /admin/ http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /admin/  http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8080/
ProxyPass / http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://aa.mcmaster.ca:8081/
```